# Question about Raw Origin in Frame System Pallet

Tags: frame, origin, frame-system

Inside mod pallet {}, there is code for RawOrigin, which is

```
pub enum RawOrigin<AccountId> {
    Root,
    Signed(AccountId),
    None,
}
```

I don't know how we can use this AccountId type explicitly, I mean shouldn't the code look like this?

```
pub enum RawOrigin<T:config::AccounId> {
    Root,
    Signed(T:config::AccountId),
    None,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should review how generics work in Rust.

By defining `RawOrigin` as `pub enum RawOrigin<AccountId>`, we allow this enum object to work for any generic `AccountId` type.

What you seem to want actually is defined in the `frame_system` pallet elsewhere:

```
/// Exposed trait-generic origin type.
#[pallet::origin]
pub type Origin<T> = RawOrigin<<T as Config>::AccountId>;
```

Here you can see we take this `RawOrigin` type, and directly use the `AccountId` definition from `Config` as you wanted.

However, doing it this way takes advantage of the `#[pallet::origin]` macro, which allows pallets to register new origins in the Substrate runtime, rather than making some hard coded assumptions about this kind of thing.

So this is a very intended abstraction, and part of the overall modular design of Substrate.